# How to cast objects of type java.lang.Class<?> without warnings?

Tags: java, generics, casting

I've got some code that looks like this:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(someClassName);
if(TargetClass.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz))
{
    Class<? extends TargetClass> narrowClass = (Class<? extends TargetClass>)clazz;
    // Use the narrowClass for stuff
}
```

This code give me an "unchecked cast" warning, probably because the `isAssignableFrom` check doesn't count as a "check". It's not possible to use `instanceof`, here, because you can't check the runtime type due to type-erasure.

Is there any way to write this code without a compiler warning? Or is the only way to get rid of the warning to add `@SupprssWarnings("unckeched")` to the method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following method:

```
 Class<? extends TargetClass> narrowClass = clazz.asSubclass(TargetClass.class);
```

Here is a [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass(java.lang.Class)) to the documentation.

Comment: Do you mean `clazz.asSubclass(TargetClass.class)`?

Comment: No, [link-only answers are discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: *facepalm* I was aware of `Class.cast` but never considered actually *reading the rest of the javadoc*. Thanks.